# Hold a bash script on PBS status without Torque

Tags: bash, queue, pbs

I've access to a low priority queue on a large national system. I can allocate in the queue only 1 job at the time.

The PBS job contains a program who is not likely to complete before the wall-time ends. Jobs on hold can't be queued in a number that exceeds 3.

#### It means that:

1. I can not use `-W depend=afterok:$ID_of_previous_job` . The script would submit all the job at once, but just the first 3 will enter the queue (the last 2 in H state)
2. I can not modify the submission script with a last line that submit the `next_job` (it is very likely that the actual program won't finish before the `walltime` ends and then the last line is not executed.
3. I can not install any software so I am limited to use a Bash Script, rather than Torque
4. I'd rather not use a "time check" script (such as: every 5 minute check if `previous_job` is over)

Is it possible to use a `while` and or `sleep` ?

Comment: I guess you should be able to use the `epilogue` option to `qsub` to start the next job.

Comment: Isn't this working only with Torque ?

Comment: I don't know if the epilogue works with non-TORQUE pbs rms or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
To use a `while` and `sleep` requires you to do something very similar to a time check script:

```
#!/bin/bash
jobid=`submit the first job`
while [[ -z `qstat ${jobid} | grep C` ]]; do
  sleep 5
done

# submit the new job once the loop is done, after checking the exit status if desired
```

**Option 2 - may be TORQUE only, not sure:**
Perhaps a better way, suggested by Dmitri Chubarov in the comments, would be to use the per-job epilogue option. To do this the compute nodes have to be able to submit jobs, but since you were considering having the final line of the job do it then this seems like a possibility.

Add to the job a perjob epilogue by adding this line to the script:
    #PBS -l epilogue=/path/to/script

And then have the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# check exit code if desired, its argument 10 to the script
# submit the next job
```